# How can I use Body tracking in Android using ARCore or some other libraries?

Tags: unity, android, augmented-reality

I know that `ARCore` on Android **doesn't support Body Tracking** like `ARKit` does. But is there some alternative or workaround to achieve it? Some other **SDKs or Libraries** or maybe even if there is some way to do it through ARCore itself?

To make it clearer I plan to use something [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xesPGTpmPw) in an AR game for Android. I plan to develop it in `Unity 2019.4.x`.

My search result in Google didn't yield a useful result as it gets mixed with ARCore Motion Tracking (which isn't what I am talking about here) or implementation with ARKit. But I got a little hope that there might be some way out after reading [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/track-whole-human-figure.743708/) on Unity Forums.

Comment: Did you find your answer? Looking for the same thing.

Comment: @TahaFarooq No, I couldn't find anything for ARCore :(

Comment: See [MediaPipe](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/pose.html). It has pose tracker api.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing something similar to [Father.io](https://father.io) for my final year project for uni.

The closest solution that I can come up with is using a third-party application/addon such as;

- OpenCV
- Tensorflow
- Vuforia

These are the first three that spring to mind and most seem to be based on OpenCV any way.

If I happen to come across a tutorial of how to implement it, I'll try and link it here.

Happy hunting.